# SSD partitioning fails internally, external OK

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, partition

I bought a Samsung SSD 850 EVO 250GB for my MacBook Pro 13'' Early 2011, but am unable to install OS X to it. (Yosemite 10.10.3)

When installing the SSD internally, OS X doesn't find the drive, and diskutil reports the following (tested with Internet Recovery, old install on external drive and own thumb drive installer):

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                       0xEE                         250.1 GB   disk0s1
```

However, when attaching the SSD via USB (externally) the following is reported by diskutil on the same machine:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *250.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS SSD                     249.7 GB   disk0s2
```

Partitioning didn't work, hangs on "Waiting for volumes to reappear…". After installing OS X on the SSD while attached via USB and reinstalling internally, drive is not found again.
Any ideas? SATA cable broken? Chipset broken?

Thank you for your help!

**Addition**: The old HDD works fine internally, but is very slow (constant beach balls, more that when used externally) and has a negotiated link speed of SATA 1.5 Gbps.

Comment: I would agree with your assumption, the SATA cable.

Comment: Addition: The included SATA-2 HDD works fine internally.

Comment: Lets assume you are using external disk utility to partition internal drive.